# Balance equation for a string-spring system: meaning of 2nd Newton's law for massless objects $m=0$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, spring, string, vibrations

The usual homogeneous one dimensional wave equation for transverse (vertical) vibrations is given by
$$u_{tt}-a^2u_{xx}=0,\qquad a=\sqrt{T/\rho}$$
where $u=u(x,t)$ is the vertical displacement, $T$ is the tension and $\rho$ is the density.

Suppose that the left end of the string ($x=0$) is attached to a spring as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I'd like to understand the boundary condition for this situation, where we suppose that the equilibrium position of the spring coincides with the equilibrium position of the string and that there is no external forces. I understand the following.

1. The displacement of the spring at time $t$ is $u(0,t)$ and thus, by Hooke's law, the spring restoring force is $F=ku(0,t)$.
2. The vertical component of the tensile force is (approximately) $V=-T u_x(0,t)$.

Therefore, the total force acting on the end of the string is
$$F+V=ku(0,t)-T u_x(0,t).$$

**Question 1:** What should this sum of forces be equal to?

I understand that if there was a mass $m$ at the end of the string, then the sum should be $mu_{tt}(0,t)$ (by second Newton's law). However, there is no mass ($m=0$). Then, at least mathematically, the balance equation should be
$$ku(0,t)-T u_x(0,t)=0.\tag{1}$$

**Question 2:** Isn't the last equation saying that the net force on the end of the string is zero? If so, shouldn't the end of the string be at rest? If so, shouldn't $u(0,t)$ be zero? If so, equation $(1)$ implies that $u_x(0,t)=0$. But this is the Neumann boundary condition according to which the end of the string is "tied to a massless ring which slides up and  down a vertical pole without friction". But this contradicts $u(0,t)=0$. So, what is the correct interpretation of equation $(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1: you can simply use Newton's third law: action and reaction are opposite: action of the string on the spring opposite to the action of the spring on the string.

For question 2: you must only take into account the forces on the string. The force exerted by the string on the spring does not act on the string !

Comment: So, the third law implies directly that $ku(0,t)-T u_x(0,t)=0$?

Comment: And $F+V$ is not the net force. The net force on the string is $F$ and the net force on the spring is $V$. Thus, there is movement. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to explain.